# cant update mysql data with json

Tags: php, mysql, json

look this my code for update data in mysql

```
$id = intval($_REQUEST['id']);
$user = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['username']);
$pass = htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['password']);

include 'koneksi.php';

$sql = "update account set username='$user',password='$pass',where user_id=$id";
$result = @mysql_query($sql);
if ($result){
    echo json_encode(array(
        'user_id' => $id,
        'username' => $user,
        'password' => $pass
        ));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('errorMsg'=>'Some errors occured.'));
}
```

;

and the result in some errors occured

how solved this :D

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: You need to put a space after `account` -> `account (`

Comment: sorry was I wrong copy and paste code , please refer back

Comment: Now you have an extra comma in your query

Comment: comman ? which is bro ? show me solve query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not posted any errors, so I am going to go based on what I know.

on this line:

```
$result = @mysql_query($sql);
```

You should remove the `@` which will supress your warnings, because you have an error in your mysql query.

Your query will evaluate to this

```
update account set username='matt', password='my_pass', where user_id=100
```

The issue is the comma after the password, there should not be one before your WHERE.

Comment: can you help me again bro , i create CRUD with jeasyui and  above code for update data but this is not work for me , please help me again